# Show Detail of Data in Bootstrap Modal based on ID

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have some edit modal and i want it to show the detail of DATA in bootsrap modal based on ID. Here is my index code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <h1 class="h3 mb-4 text-gray-800"><?= $title; ?> </h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">

            <?= form_error('menu', '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">','</div>'); ?>
            <?= $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>

            <a href="<?= base_url('admin/adduser');?>" class="btn btn-primary mb-4">Tambah User</a>

            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">No</th>
                        <th scope="col">Nama</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">Password</th>
                        <th scope="col">Role</th>
                        <th scope="col">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php $i = 1; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($userRole as $u) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><?= $i ; ?></th>
                        <td><?= $u['name']; ?> </td>
                        <td><?= $u['email']; ?> </td>
                        <td><?= $u['password']; ?> </td>
                        <td><?= $u['role']; ?> </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="" class="badge badge-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#editRoleModal">edit</a>
                            <a href="<?= base_url('admin/deleteuser/') . $u['id'];?>"
                                class="badge badge-danger">delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $i++ ; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

And here is my modal :

```
<!-- Modal Edit-->
<div class="modal fade" id="editRoleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit User</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>

            <?= form_open_multipart('admin/usermanagement'); ?>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <!-- <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label> -->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="<?= $user['name']; ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <!-- <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label> -->
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="<?= $user['email']; ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <!-- <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label> -->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"
                        value="<?= $user['password']; ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <!-- <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label> -->
                    <select name="menu_id" id="menu_id" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select Role</option>
                        <?php foreach ($user_role as $u) : ?>
                        <option value="<?= $u['id']; ?>"><?= $u['role']; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For now It shows the data based on ID, but when i try to click edit button of another data, it show the same detail of one ID only.

I hope that every i click every data button, it shows different detail based on id. I've check similar case already but no one of them that work on my code. I just know my code need some jquery, but i just new on it.

Comment: You need to use JavaScript to fetch the right data into the modal (probably by using AJAX to fetch it from the server based on the ID which was clicked in the link, or by extracting it from the HTML). It's unclear what you've actually tried or what the specific issue was...the general solution to this has been shown online many times. We're not a free write-my-code service and we see no value in repetition of the same general solutions. If you need to some help, please provide a [mre] of what you actually tried, and explain specifically where you got stuck. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: One way is to move the model inside the loop

Comment: The Bootstrap 5 modal page has an example for [Varying modal content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#varying-modal-content). "_I just know my code need some jquery_" Not jquery per se, but Javascript

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i will try my best. For now, solution from @Saad is work for me, but like brombeer said, it will be inneffective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like saad said, place it inside the loop

```html
<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <h1 class="h3 mb-4 text-gray-800"><?= $title; ?> </h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">

            <?= form_error('menu', '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">','</div>'); ?>
            <?= $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>

            <a href="<?= base_url('admin/adduser');?>" class="btn btn-primary mb-4">Tambah User</a>

            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">No</th>
                        <th scope="col">Nama</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">Password</th>
                        <th scope="col">Role</th>
                        <th scope="col">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php $i = 1; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($userRole as $u) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><?= $i ; ?></th>
                        <td><?= $u['name']; ?> </td>
                        <td><?= $u['email']; ?> </td>
                        <td><?= $u['password']; ?> </td>
                        <td><?= $u['role']; ?> </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="" class="badge badge-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#editRoleModal<?=$i?>">edit</a>
                            <a href="<?= base_url('admin/deleteuser/') . $u['id'];?>"
                                class="badge badge-danger">delete</a>

                                <!-- Modal Edit-->
                                <div class="modal fade" id="editRoleModal<?=$i?>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit User</h5>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                            </div>

                                            <?= form_open_multipart('admin/usermanagement'); ?>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <div class="mb-3">
                                                    <!-- <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label> -->
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="<?= $u['name']; ?>">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="mb-3">
                                                    <!-- <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label> -->
                                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="<?= $u['email']; ?>">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="mb-3">
                                                    <!-- <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label> -->
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"
                                                        value="<?= $u['password']; ?>">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="mb-3">
                                                    <!-- <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label> -->
                                                    <select name="menu_id" id="menu_id" class="form-control">
                                                        <option value="">Select Role</option>
                                                        <?php foreach ($user_role as $u2) : ?>
                                                        <option value="<?= $u2['id']; ?>"><?= $u2['role']; ?></option>
                                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                                            </div>

                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $i++ ; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: While not wrong, this is a very ineffective way that could make the page unnecessarily long (to load) depending on how many items there are in the loop, especially when Bootstrap modals have ways to load content dynamically